# Upgraded a VC++ 6 to Visual Studio 2010 - DoModal is failing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I upgraded a VC++ 6 project and only one of the dialog's work. All the others end up getting an assertion error in occcont.cpp line 925 - ASSERT(IsWindow(pTemp->m_hWnd));

This doesn't happen for all the controls it's trying to create for this dialog only 3 out of 56.

I can't figure out what could be causing it. I'm running on Win 7 64 bit but the app is built for 32 bit.

I tried running the .exe in XP SP2 compatibility mode but that didn't work.

Could there be a setting I need to change for this?

Also, can I view a form designer? I can't seem to locate any sort of option for it. I thought if I could bring up the designer it might provide some better insight.

Comment: Can you step in and debug at that point to see the stack trace and find which dialog is triggering this?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't really help. All dialog's except 1 are causing this problem.

Comment: Is there a shared control that all of those dialogs have that the working one does not have (like an ActiveX control or some OCX)?

Comment: Nope. They're all pretty basic controls except the one that does work is very simple. It only has 4 text fields and 2 buttons. The other ones have radio buttons and checkboxes as well.

Comment: Try this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949107, it talks about ensuring the proper ActiveX controls are registered on the machine. It may help, it could be a red herring.

Comment: I had looking into that already and didn't find it to be helpful. It didn't actually list which controls may not be registered. I will double check to make sure I'm not missing an active x control...

Comment: It turned out there was an activex control missing. It's funny because I asked the guy who developed this app and he said there were no active x controls used.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using some sort of an AciveX controls and creation fails. Make sure that control is properly registered.
Another possibility is that control is still somehow dependent on the old MFC library that is not present in your system.